# @Profile doesn't work with Messaging gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, profile

In my integration application, i define a simple gateway as following:

```
@MessagingGateway
@Profile(value = { "export" })
public interface ExportingOutboundGateway {

     @Gateway(requestChannel = "exportChannel")
     void send(RequestInfo request);
}
```

If i execute this Spring boot application with ***spring.profiles.active=export*** declared in application.properties, the gateway bean couldn't be created

Is there any mistake over the definition of the gateway bean ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the `IntegrationComponentScanRegistrar`. When we scan for `@MessagingGateway` interfaces we don't honor an `Environment` from the application context and an internal `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` just uses a default one where we don't have that active profile.

As a workaround I suggest to have it like this:

```
@Bean
@Profile("export")
public AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean exportingOutboundGateway() {
    return new AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean(ExportingOutboundGateway.class);
}

...

public interface ExportingOutboundGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "exportChannel")
    void send(String request);

}
```

A JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4565

Comment: Thank Artem Bilan, by the way, it still works with system properties source, isn't it ?

Comment: If you mean for profiles, then yes, it doesn't matter what is the source for your profile activation.

Comment: Yes, i mean profiles. Thanks ! I 'm going to try the workaround